# Exec is not working

Tags: php, magento, magmi

I am trying to automate magmi with a script

```
<?php
class Trainingsatyendra_Feedback_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
        public function indexAction()
        {

    exec('localhost/practice/magmi/web/magmi_run.php?mode=create&pr
    ofile=default&engine=magmi_productimportengine:Magmi_ProductImportEngine&CSV:f
    ilename=catalog_product_20130422_073721.csv',$result);
        var_dump($result);
         if($result)
        {
        echo "shell successfully executed";
        }
        else
        echo "shell Not executed";

        } 
    }

    ?>
```

The above code is written in my controller file.
when i copy and paste the the below code in browser url it works giving me output on the browser

```
localhost/practice/magmi/web/magmi_run.php?mode=create&pr
ofile=default&engine=magmi_productimportengine:Magmi_ProductImportEngine&CSV:f
ilename=catalog_product_20130422_073721.csv
```

However it dosen't work if i try to use exec or shell_exec in my controller.

Comment: add http:// before localhost?

Comment: You don't `exec` scripts on web servers. You do it with executables in your file system. Any program you can run in the command line you should be able to run using `exec`.

Comment: @chandresh_cool did you mean something like `wget http://localhost...`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763997/shell-run-execute-php-script-with-parameters

Comment: @Havelock yes you are right.

Comment: Does shell_exec makes any difference ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_Import_Url_UI) you either have to use `wget`, i.e.

```
exec('wget http://localhost/practice/magmi/web/magmi_run.php?mode=create&profile=default&engine=magmi_productimportengine:Magmi_ProductImportEngine&CSV:filename=catalog_product_20130422_073721.csv');
```

or use an appropriate `cli command`, i.e.

```
exec('magmi [cli_command']);
```

or maybe even better you use [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to fetch whatever is needed over HTTP(S).

Comment: No, the above soln is not working not wget nor cURL is working

Answer (score 1):

I was also seeing the same response but after few tries ended up changing the folder permissions to apache:apache the user which the service apache was running with and it worked.