# How do I pass parameter from $_GET to shell_exec and run it on PHP CLI?

Tags: php

I need to pass some $usertoken value to shell_exec function inorder to execute another PHP file with this value from my server.

Here is my code :

```
<?php
$usertoken= array( $_GET['usertoken'] );
$findme   = 'valid_device';
$pos = strpos($usertoken, $findme);

if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$usertoken'";
} else {
    echo " Device is valid ### $usertoken Continue to push_script  ### ";
    echo shell_exec('cd /mypath; /usr/local/bin/php -q push_script.php -q "{$usertoken}"');
    }
?>
```

The push_script.php is waiting with $_GET to the $usertoken value

How can I pass this argument to the PHP ?

I understood from what I was reading that I should use maybe some parse_str() with combination of $argv in order to parse the $usertoken to the PHP script but I can't figure it out how to do it.

I will appreciate any help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shell run/execute php script with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763997/shell-run-execute-php-script-with-parameters)

Answer (score 2):

Variables aren't expanded inside single-quoted strings, only inside double-quoted strings, so swap your quotes.

```
echo shell_exec("cd /mypath; /usr/local/bin/php -q push_script.php -q '{$usertoken}'");
```

[What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Also, `$usertoken` should just be a string, not an array, so the assignment should be:

```
$usertoken = $_GET['usertoken'];
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I changed to single-quoted but it still doesn't work.
The value is passed to the PHP script but then the script output a reslut error that mean the value is incorrect.
Maybe the problem is with the shell_exec syntax ?

Comment: Does it work if you run `php -q push_script.php -q 'token'` from the command line?

Comment: `shell_exec` looks fine. Are you sure you need the extra `-q` after `push_script.php`? That argument gets sent to the script.

Comment: Running the `php push_script.php 'token_number'` from the command line is working fine but still the same problem - the PHP result with error which means that from some reason the string value didn't pass correctly.
And yes I don't need the -q

Comment: Well ignore my last comment I thought you want me to run the frist php script.
Well indeed it is very strange - running the `php push_script.php 'token'`  from the command line result with the error output.
BTW, when running the push_script via the web with php?usertoken=XXX is working fine.
So I don't understand what could be the problem ?
Maybe some server configuration ?

Comment: I found what was the problem. It appears that when you trying to run PHP CLI in some server environment you should use the following path : `/usr/local/php54/bin/php-cli` that probably change from each server.
Now I can run the script with parameter.
Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

You will get your value in reserved variable [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

In `push_script.php` `$argv[1]` will get you desired parameter passed, Also swap your quotes as @Barmar indicated.

Comment: Hi Kamal thank for the suggestion but I didn't understand how do I use the $argv .
Do I need to replace it in the `push script.php` instead of the `$_get()`
or is it in addition ?
Should I also add something in the execution script ?

Comment: @Abraham you need to replace `$_GET['usertoken']` with `$argv[1]` .. as far as I know `$_GET` would be served under `http / https` (may be more, which I am not aware of ), I had already posted link to PHP Manual for ref in my answer. here again http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

See this post too.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763997/shell-run-execute-php-script-with-parameters

Comment: @Abraham you can `print_r($argv)`, and see all your params where 0 index will be the file which you are executing .. or if you like to use `$_GET` .. you can execute you script via curl or wget.. like `curl <options> http://yourdomain.com/script_to_be_executed.php'

Comment: thanks It works ! and it's indeed goo solution when you want to combine https request and passing on the parameter to PHP CLI script