# Replacing $_GET to make it work from command line

Tags: php, linux, command-line, get

Currently I have this small script that makes it possible to check if a domain name is free. It works from the browser, when you type check.php?domain=xxxx.com and you see if it is free or not.

Because of $_GET is used it only works from a browser and not from command line.

The PHP manual says that I should use $argv or getopt() to achieve this. I have tried it but then my script stops working.

How can the following code be made to work from command line?

```
<?php
include_once('/home/xxx/API.php');  
$CClient = new XCApi();
$CClient->isAvailable();
$d = $_GET['domain'];
ob_implicit_flush(1);

for ($i = 0; $i < 60000; ++$i) {

$domainResult = $CClient->checkDomainAvailability( new XDomain( $d ) );

if ( $domainResult->getStatus() == "domain_available" ) {
    echo $i . ". Domain " . $d . " is free (checked: " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . ")<br />";

    $_GET['domain'] = $d;
    include_once('Register.php');
    exit;

} 
elseif ( $domainResult->getStatus() == "domain_unavailable" ) {
    echo $i . ". Domain " . $d . " is unavailable (checked: " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . ")<br />";
}
else {
    echo $i . ". Domain " . $d . " is unknown (checked: " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . ")<br />";
}
echo"<pre>";
print_r($domainResult);
echo"</pre>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$d = $_GET['domain'];
```

to:

```
$d = $argv[1];
```

...and call it at the command line like this:

```
php /path/to/script.php "www.domaintocheck.com"
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, but it does not work. I get no output, just a black screen. Like I type clear in command.

Comment: This worked. I had forgotten to end the scrip with } Thank you :)

Comment: This works as long as the SSH session is open. Once I close the session, the code stops working.

Comment: Try calling it at the command line like: `nohup php /path/to/script.php "www.domaintocheck.com" > /dev/null 2>&1 &` - you need to ignore SIGHUP (`nohup`) and detach it from the calling terminal (`> /dev/null 2>&1 &`). If you schedule it as a cron job you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 3):

write another scripts that reads command args and puts them in a $_GET array, then include this file.

```
#!/...
<?php
$_GET = array(
'domain' => $argv[1]
);

include 'yourscript.php';
```

or just put that bit at the top of (a copy of) your file

Comment: I tried this but get 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' in /home/xxx/scrip.php on line 3

Comment: Array creation syntax is wrong, it should be `array('domain'=>$argv[1])`

Answer (score 0):

Replace...

```
$d = $_GET['domain'];
```

with...

```
$d = $argv[1];
```

for a command-line version.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of this: [PHP passing $_GET in linux command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186392/php-passing-get-in-linux-command-prompt)

Another possible way in Linux is to use curl (change localhost to your server's domain name):

```
curl http://localhost/check.php?domain=xxxx.com
```

Finally, the simple-stupid way is to check if $_GET['domain'] or $argv[1] or getopt('domain:') is set.

In that way your script will work both from http request or from the command line.