# Include Local PHP File and Pass Parameters

Tags: php, include

I'd like to avoid doing any needless HTTP requests on my site to improve performance. So, I'd like to include a local PHP on my server *without* using cURL. The problem is that the PHP I'm calling expects some parameters to be passed via HTTP GET. I'd like to keep it that way since I also want to be able to access those PHP files from other places.

What is the best way of doing this? Can I access the *output* of a local PHP file while giving it GET parameters?

Comment: See if you have `allow_url_fopen` enabled from php.ini.

Comment: @Sarfraz Even if he does, that command would not include the script it would include the output of the script. Also, you would need allow `allow_url_include` to be enabled as well in order for it work. Plus you should *never* include stuff via HTTP anyway. Ever.

Comment: @DaveRandom: That's correct I just focused on his error :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like to avoid doing any needless HTTP requests on my site to improve performance

`include` also makes an HTTP request when you supply an HTTP URI to it, so instead of the client's asynchronous include (for example using AJAX or an iframe) you do it synchronously on the server, therefore making the page load even slower.

So while the include may work as intended (you want to include the **output**, right?), it will definitely not speed up your site.

> the PHP I'm calling expects some parameters to be passed via HTTP GET. I'd like to keep it that way since I also want to be able to access those PHP files from other places.

Then alter those files and set the appropriate variables before including them. Or even better, refactor it into functions. For example, if the file you want to include looks like this:

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
print "User: $username";
```

Then refactor into a function and store in a separate file:

```
function PrintUsername($username)
{
    print "User: $username";
}
```

And call it appropriately:

```
include('printusername.php');
PrintUsername($_GET['username']);
```

(You might want to throw in an `isset()` here and there.) Now you can alter your code that also needs this output:

```
include('printusername.php');
PrintUsername($someOtherVariable);
```

Now you don't have to rely on URL or `$_GET` or `include` magic, but simply use all functions as they're meant to.

Comment: Is there another way of including output. I'm already using cURL at the moment and it's *very* slow (accessing 3 PHPs per request).

Comment: @Hassan yes, by using AJAX requests from the client.

Comment: Any way of getting them from the server? They're sitting right next to each other after all!

Comment: @Hassan then simply alter those scripts and include them directly. See edit.

Comment: I think "refactor" is an understatement :) I just spent an hour "refactoring" a single page on my site. Well, it works now, thanks!

Comment: @Hassan nice, happy to help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're on a linux box, you could exec the script and pick up the output with something like:

`exec ("php myPhpFile.php arg1 arg2 arg3 > myPhpOutput.html");`

then open the outputted file for read.

For this to work however (and it is ugly!) you would need to modify myPhpFile and implement a method to test for $_GET paramaters. If it doesn't find them then load the properties using [argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

---

Improvement (I was thinking lazily :))

shell_exec will return the output as a string. so
`$filecontents = shell_exec("php yourfile.php arg1 arg2 arg3...");`
 will return the processed output of a php file.

Comment: exec's second param can also be given to fill an array with lines of output. So it's up to how you want your output returned.
[shell_exec](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)
[exec](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Comment: Probably the most interesting answer here. Thanks, I'll look into this too!

Comment: You are velkom!
Spotted [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186392/php-passing-get-in-linux-command-prompt) too. The top answer has a nice and tidy method for catching your args using [getOpt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php)

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly, but works.

```
$_GET['foo'] = 1;
$_GET['bar'] = 2;
include '/path/to/file.php';
```

Comment: Yes, this is the answer I arrived at when I asked a related (but different) question. The implementation in my case is exactly how you described it: ugly.

Comment: This is *wrong* in many ways, and it's not even supported anymore in the latest PHP version. You will get an error if you do this.

Comment: @Radu I didn't say it is the *right* way. I said it just works. Use it only in your last efforts.

Comment: @Radu I'm not disagreeing with you on the point that this should not be done is actually wrong (`allow_url_include` strikes again), but `it's invalid in the latest PHP version` - in what way? AFAIK you *can* do this, you just shouldn't.

Comment: @bsdnoobz - but it doesn't work. DaveRandom, it *is* invalid. Try this with PHP 5.4 and you *will* get an error. I have a legacy application that uses this all over the place, and it was a *real pain* trying to get it to work with PHP 5.4. I eventually gave up. This is the kind of practice that makes your application non-future-proof and severely limits your possibilities of growth. Bad practice is named "bad practice" for a reason...

Comment: @Radu Which part of it causes an error? Testing on PHP 5.4.3/Apache 2.4.2/Win32 I cannot get any part of the above procedure to fail. Let me re-iterate I'm definitely **not** advocating this approach, but I would like to understand what part of it *will not work* and, more to the point, why.

Comment: @DaveRandom, you're right, I just tested this now and it does indeed work (I remembered I had a huge issue with a terribly bad practice connected to `$_GET`, but I didn't remember accurately what the issue was). What *doesn't* work anymore is defining functions that take `$_GET` as an argument. For example, this will not work anymore: `function a($_GET) { }`. This is another terribly bad practice, and it doesn't work anymore because in PHP 5.4 you cannot re-assign superglobals.

Comment: @Radu OMG I can't believe anyone would ever have done that. Oh wait, I forgot where I was for a second... It seems that `function a($_GET) { }` is the *only* thing that you can't do (that I can find) - you can still do `$_GET = 1;` on a line on it's own and it will work without complaining. Again, not that you *would*, but you *can*. If PHP is going to start complaining when you do stupid things that should be one of them - although the first one is easy to detect because it's creating a function signature at parse, whereas the other is done at run time and could be dynamic.