# PHP passing value in command prompt in Window

Tags: php, cmd

I would like to use cmd to execute my php file, and I need to pass a value to the php via the command prompt just like we pass a get value to it in the browser, following is my code

```
<?php
$mail = getopt('mail:');
print $mail['mail'];
mail($mail['mail'], 'Mercury test mail', 'If you can read this, everything was fine!');
?>
```

and here is the command I input inthe cmd:

```
php.exe -e C:\xampp\htdocs\Me\mail.php -mail=me@gmail.com
```

But the command prompt returns undefined index: mail,
And here is the message shown in the error log:

```
[27-Jul-2012 04:17:07 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: mail in C:\xampp\htdocs\Me\mail.php on line 3
[27-Jul-2012 04:17:07 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: mail in C:\xampp\htdocs\Me\mail.php on line 4
[27-Jul-2012 04:17:07 UTC] PHP Warning:  mail(): SMTP server response: 503 No valid recipients specified. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Me\mail.php on line 4
```

I just follow the way mentioned here: [PHP passing $_GET in linux command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186392/php-passing-get-in-linux-command-prompt) , but it does not work, then how should I change my code in order to acheive the task?

Answer (score 0):

This code will return you an array of arguments passed in the command line.

```
<?php
var_dump($argv);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try argv :

```
<?php 
$email = argv[0];
mail($email, 'Mercury test mail', 'If you can read this, everything was fine!');
?>
```

Usage :

```
php script.php email@email.com
```

Comment: ya, if I use argv, problem can be solved. Actually, this is a good way to do so if I only need to pass one parameter, but sometimes I may need to pass more values, say a few, then if I can pass the values like using GET method, so with the name of parameters, this will be more convenient to do so, that's why I would like to ask

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, have you checked to see if $argv and $argc contain values?  Create a simple test PHP script which 'echo's the value of $argc and use the print_r() function to display the value of $argv.

```
<?
echo "Argc = $argc";
print_r($argv);
?>
```

Then run this script as

```
php.exe [script file name].php -test -etc...
```

Also, try passing values using slashes instead of dashes.  For example:

```
php.exe [script name].php /option1 /option2 ...
```

If $argc and $argv contain the appropriate values, all you have to do is parse them into your desired variables.

Comment: This is how I change my code to see if value can be passed <?php
 $mail = $argv[1];
 print $mail;
 mail($mail, 'Mercury test mail', 'If you can read this, everything was fine!');
?>
However, if there are many values need to be passed in, I think having something like -mail=me@gmail.com, so to pass the variable by the variable's name, it will be less confused