# Can I pass $_GET parameters to a script running locally?

Tags: php, shell, command-line

I'm trying to launch from the command line:

```
$ /usr/bin/php -f "index.php?refresh_words=1"
Could not open input file: index.php?refresh_words=1
```

Off course, without `?refresh_words=1` it's running ok. Can I pass $_GET parameters from the command line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186392/php-passing-get-in-linux-command-prompt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do this that way. Use `argv` and `argc`. See [Command Line Usage](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) section in manual