# How to pass GET variables to php file with Shell?

Tags: php, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP passing $_GET in linux command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186392/php-passing-get-in-linux-command-prompt)

i want execute php file with Shell script but i dont know how i can pass GET variables.

This script "php script.php?var=data" don't work because Shell can't find the file "script.php?var=data".

So ,do you know how i can pass my variables ? If it's really impossible to use GET variable, can i pass variables by an other way and use it in my php script ?

Comment: Better than the selected answer: use "php-cgi" executable instead of "php".  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11965479/543738

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're executing your script via the command-line (such as `php your_script.php`), you will not be able to use the `$_GET` parameters, as you're experiencing.

However, you can make use of PHP's CLI which graciously gives you the [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) array.

To use it, you will call your script like this:

```
php your_script.php variable1 "variable #2"
```

Inside your script, you can access the variables with:

```
<?php

$variable1 = $argv[1];
$variable2 = $argv[2];

?>
```

Comment: One thing that needs to be added - this method relies on the assumption that the user supplies the arguments in the same order. you can also pass "full argument" (i.e php your_script.php "id=10") and then create your own key=>val array

Comment: Newfurniturey : This method looks perfect to what i need, thank you very much ! =).
TheSimon : Thank for precisions.

Answer (score 2):

My idea would be to write some kind of wrapper script to feed to /usr/bin/php and give that a string of arguments to grab the data from.  Make no mistake, it is a hack and probably not a good one at that, but it should get the job done.

```
<?php
/** Wrapper.php
 **
 ** Description: Adds the $_GET hash to a shell-ran PHP script
 **
 ** Usage:       $ php Wrapper.php <yourscript.php> arg1=val1 arg2=val2 ...
**/

//Grab the filenames from the argument list
$scriptWrapperFilename = array_shift($argv); // argv[0]
$scriptToRunFilename = array_shift($argv); // argv[1]

// Set some restrictions
if (php_sapi_name() !== "cli")
    die(" * This should only be ran from the shell prompt!\n");

// define the $_GET hash in global scope
$_GET;

// walk the rest and pack the $_GET hash
foreach ($argv as $arg) {
    // drop the argument if it's not a key/val pair
    if(strpos($arg, "=") === false)
        continue;

    list($key, $value) = split("=", $arg);

    // pack the $_GET variable
    $_GET[$key] = $arg;
}

// get and require the PHP file we're trying to run
if (is_file($scriptToRunFilename))
    require_once $scriptToRunFilename;
else
    die(" * Could not open `$scriptToRunFilename' for inclusion.\n");

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP CLI takes variables within a command structure like:

```
php woop.php --path=/home/meow/cat.avi
```

You can then use something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php to get that option like so in your PHP script:

```
getopt('path')
```

Or you can get them directly form `argv`.

As an alternative as @GBD says you can use a bash script to wget a page of your site as well.