# cant get value from parameter in function

Tags: php, function, get

anyone knows why i cant $_GET the name parameter in here?

its says i have an undefined index on name
which normaly means i cant read the parameter
my url is

/data/content/de/home/write?name=123&password=123

kinda clueless right now :/

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'write?name=') !== false){
    $sUrl=array_reverse(explode('?',substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1)));
    $sUrl=str_replace('write','',$sUrl[1]).'index.html';
    if($sUrl=='index.html'){
            $sUrl='data/content'.'/'.$language.'/'.$home.'/index.html';;
    };
    ----->>!! echo $_GET['name']; !!<-----      
}else{
    if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'write') !== false){
        $sUrl=str_replace('write','',substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1)).'index.html';
        $login='true';
        if($sUrl=='index.html'){
            $sUrl='data/content'.'/'.$language.'/'.$home.'/index.html';;
        };
    } else {
        $sUrl=substr($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'],1);
    };
};
```

tia hvlmnns

**EDIT**

http://hvlmnns.de/write?name=1223&password=123
http://hvlmnns.de/write/?name=1223&password=123

after some struggeling i found this issue
since the form gets submitted per jquery i think there is a way to put that slash in there..
strange thing tho shouldnt it read the params wenether the slash is there or not?

Comment: Did you try a var_dump of $_GET to see what you get?

Comment: done that right now; its NULL

Comment: Are you running this through the CLI, or through a webserver?

Comment: ClI aka xampp on win7.. okay tested it on my webspace seems to work

Comment: Yes, you can't use _GET using the CLI. Here's a good post regarding that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186392/php-passing-get-in-linux-command-prompt

Comment: @user2658774 all my other stuff with get works strangely its just in that condition

Comment: and i think i got you wrong :) CLI is basicly a home linux etc server and you think im trying to run that on it or? if so thats not the case im using an apache on windows known as xampp

Comment: Does it work if you create a new script that just prints out the $_GET variable? You aren't modifying the _GET array in any way, are you? You can also do a var_dump on $_REQUEST and see if it gets populated in there.

Answer (score 0):

What is your $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] evaluating as?

IIRC: The query string following the ? is not included in the request_uri.

Try using $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']

Comment: good try but since get is a global function and im not trying to get it from my uri; additionally it works on my server so the code is right

Comment: Whoops, I misunderstood the initial question. Apologies!