# Executing PHP file with POST or GET params via SSH?

Tags: php, ssh

I need to run php file in terminal with some parameters. But without sending of http request, just server side operation.

Tryed to do

```
php /path/file.php?a=1
```

but got an error `Error: Command failed: Could not open input file: /path/file.php?a=1`

Is that possible to do? Or maybe something similar to it?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP passing $\_GET in linux command prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186392/php-passing-get-in-linux-command-prompt)

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass GET or POST params via Shell, because those rely on the HTTP protocoll.

You could try using command line parameters. Check out this article for more:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php