# Call PHP from Python with subprocess

Tags: php, python, python-2.7

my Python script was :

```
base_url = "http://server.com/sync.php?"
phone_url = "phone=%s" % "12345678"
pass_url = "pass=%s" % "xxxxxxxxx"
verif_url = "u=%s" % "12345678"
url =  base_url + "%s&%s&%s" % (phone_url,pass_url,verif_url)
req = urllib.urlopen(url)
the_page = req.read()
```

the url look like : http://server.com/sync.php?phone=123456781&pass=xxxxxxxxx&u=12345678

Working fine but it's very slow...

So i tried use Subprocess :

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("php ./sync.php", "shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
script_response = proc.stdout.read()
```

How i can send the parameters? (phone, pass,u)

The content of my php file :

```
$username = $_GET["phone"];
$password = $_GET["pass"];
$u = $_GET["u"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide the parameters to `Popen` you should store them in a list:

```
cmd = ["php", "./sync.php"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

You can see the [Popen help](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) that the first parameter `args` *should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single string*.

Note also that you can use the `cwd` parameter to precise the current directory.

Comment: Ok so for my exemple cmd = ["php", "./sync.php", "?phone=%s" % phone_url "&pass=%s" % pass_url "&u=%s" % verif_url] ?

Comment: i don't know from a terminal, but from my browser : http://server.com/sync.php?phone=123456781&pass=xxxxxxxxx&u=12345678

Comment: You cannot pass HTTP GET parameters through the PHP cli. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186392/php-passing-get-in-linux-command-prompt

Comment: Work with :

cmd = ["php-cgi", "-f", "./codephp/sync.php", "phone=%s" % phone_u, "pass=%s" % pass_u, "u=%s" % verif_u]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

But slower than urllib.urlopen

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling the sub process incorrectly.

*P.S. Don't use relative path, use absolute path.*

Can you try this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("php /path/to/your/sync.php arg1 arg2 argN", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
script_response = proc.stdout.read()
```

Comment: i don't understand wich syntax i need use : "php /sync.php phone_url pass_url verif_url" ?