# Add current date to PHP command line argument

Tags: php

I'm trying to use PHP command line (from cron tab). I know how to add arguments like this:

```
cd /home/users/public_html/; php -f script.php some_value
```

I would like (or need) to add current date dinamically:

```
cd /home/users/public_html/; php -f script.php current_date
```

With wget I did this:

```
wget "https://mysitecom/script.php?currentdate=`date +\%s.\%N`"
```

But I can not find any way to do something similar wih a php command line.

I've tried:

```
 cd /home/users/public_html/; php -f script.php `date+\%s.\%N`
```

And I get the error "Command not found".

I've tried also the solution proposed in one answer:

```
 cd /home/users/public_html/; php -f script.php date+\%s.\%N
```

And I get the literal string `"date+\%s.\%N"`

With the other proposed solution:

```
 cd /home/users/public_html/; php -f script.php "$(date +"%s.%N")"
```

I get these errors in the email sent by the cron:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Passing via `$_GET` *may* work, but is not the best practice here. It looks like you may be using the PHP CGI API.

Comment: I can understand but in that case, saying GET variables are not available through command line is not true and cofused me. Even worse, the @RiggsFolly's answer said "GET variables are called arguments in command line" what is also not true, I've been reading docuemtation and they are not called differently in different contexts, they are totally different things. Anyway, I still would like to dinamically add current date to command line argument or to GET variable.

Comment: @RiggsFolly is right - GET variables are not available for the CLI unless you're using PHP CGI. If you're using the true CLI you can only pass arguments.

Comment: Ok. Totally understand now. Anyway, I can not accept your answer, it explains something I was understanding wrong but not how can I pass current date to script from command line. I've also edited the question to remove all the confusion between GET and arguments.

Comment: There you go, it is all nicely layed out on a plate for you.
PS Its not allowed to change the focus of your question after it has been answered

Comment: The focus is how to pass current date from command line to a PHP script. I was confused about GET variables and arguments, that doesn't change the focus of the question from my point of view. Please, read my first comment in your answer, I said the same thing from the beginning: your answer make me understand the difference between GET and command line arguments but " could you add a example of how to add current date to command line arguments".

Comment: You are now being really rude. I did my own research first, you can be sure. Sorry if you feel annoyed (I feel I'm bothering you, what is not my intention at all). As you can see in my question I'm using `date +\%s.\%N` when used wget, I know that command but it was not working for me when I tried to use it with php command line. I'm going to try it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've made it work. It was a syntax error:

This:

```
cd /home/users/public_html/; php -f script.php `date+\%s.\%N`
```

Need to be:

```
 cd /home/users/public_html/; php -f script.php `date +\%s.\%N`
```

Answer (score 1):

When using PHP from the command line (CLI) they are not called GET variables they are called arguments

There are 2 parameters passed to every script run from the command line called [$argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) and [$argc](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

One thing to remember the first `argv[0]` occurance holds the name of the script that is being run. Other than that the arguments appear in `$argv[]` in the order thay appear on the command line

argc is a count of how many variables have been passed to the script

arcv is an array of all the variables passed

If its any help they are just like the "C" equivalents if you have ever written any "C" code

***ADDITIONAL INFO***

To call your script with todays date use something like this

```
cd /home/users/public_html/; php -f script.php "$(date +"%s.%N")"
```

adjust the format as required.

Although if you want todays date in the script I am not sure why you would not get that from within the PHP script itself.

Comment: Obvious, GET variables are for GET requests. Can you add a example of how to add current date to command line arguments?

Comment: Depending on the date format `php -f myscript.php 20150818` where `20150818` is argument 1 (argument 0 is the script itself)

Comment: @JayBlanchard that is not an option, I need it always current date, so it must be dinamically added.

Comment: Then use the Linux `date` as the argument.

Comment: I've made some tests and arguments passed in command line are available in $_GET in my PHP script. Can you explain it?

Comment: No they are not, not if the script is run from the command line

Comment: Explain what? How the arguments are available in the PHP script?

Comment: No, explain why I access to $_GET variables from command line, see my edited questions.

Comment: The only explanation I can come up with is that you are executing the `php-cgi.exe` and not the `php.exe` [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186392/php-passing-get-in-linux-command-prompt/11965479#11965479)

Comment: As you can see in my question, I tried date command with no success. I'm going to try it again.

Comment: It doesn't work. I get the string `"date+"%Y%m%d"` in `$argv`

Comment: Did you put the `date+"%Y%m%d` in double quotes like `"date+"%Y%m%d""` if so try without the double quotes around the whole parameter

Comment: Ok I did a little more research. I fired up a Ubuntu VM and looked on  t'internet and this works at least in Ubuntu. See the answer I have changed the format of the command line call to get the date and tested it and it works

Comment: I cannot use `"$(date+"%s./%N")"` or `"$(date +"%s./%N")"`. I get two errors: line 0: **unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'**  and **syntax error: unexpected end of file**. But I'm not sure what that means. I will keep with my answer. Maybe it has something to do with the configuration of my server?

Comment: It is not fixed, and I'm not get your code wokring. I've tried also "$(date +"%s.%N")", "$(date +%s.%N)", $(date +%s.%N) ... all of them trigger EOF errors. The only working code for me is `date +\%s.\%N`

Comment: What OS are you using, just for my reference

Comment: I'm on CentOS, not sure if that matters. Server stuff is a mistery for me.