# Run php script with parameters by cron

Tags: php, parameters, cron

i have file cron .sh; there is calling php script with parameter

```
php -f /adr1/adr2/nejaky_kod.php?par1=val1
```

I think command is bad, true is ( ? ):

```
php -f /adr1/adr2/nejaky_kod.php "par1=val1"
```

Is it right ?

After succesfull I want read parameter from script. How can I make it :
$inputval = $_GET['par1'];

Thanks for advice !

Comment: Command line arguments are in `$argv`, not `$_GET`.

Comment: `$argv[1] == "par1=val1"`

Comment: you can pass arguments in the php command but it's not gonna go in `$_GET`

Comment: Have a look at this [$argv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP passing $\_GET in linux command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186392/php-passing-get-in-linux-command-prompt)

Answer (score 0):

Thans ! I solved my question. Syntax for run in cron is

php -f /adr1/adr2/nejaky_kod.php "parameter"

and in php i read argument like:

$_GET['value'] = $argv[1];