# Python Web Server Not Handling POST Requests Correctly

Tags: python, php, html, http-post, webserver

I've created a simple web server using Python. The server is designed to handle both GET and POST requests for PHP and HTML files. GET requests seem to be working fine, but I'm encountering issues with POST requests.

Here's the relevant part of my Python server code:

```
import socket
import os

PORT = 2728

# Function to serve PHP files
def serve_php(client, filename):
    # Send HTTP headers indicating successful response
    client.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n")
    client.sendall(b"Content-Type: text/html\n\n")

    # Read the content of the file
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        content = f.read()

    # Find PHP code blocks and execute them
    while "<?php" in content:
        start = content.index("<?php")
        end = content.index("?>", start)
        php_code = content[start+5:end].strip()
        
        # Execute PHP code and replace in content
        php_output = os.popen(f"php -r '{php_code}'").read()
        content = content[:start] + php_output + content[end+2:]

    # Send the modified content back to the client
    client.sendall(content.encode())

# Function to handle client requests
def handle_client(client):
    data = client.recv(1024).decode()
    
    if data:
        # Parse the request method and requested file
        request_method = data.split(" ")[0]
        file_requested = data.split(" ")[1]

        # If it's a GET request and the file is a PHP file
        if request_method == "GET" and file_requested.endswith(".php"):
            filename = os.path.join("htdocs", file_requested[1:])
            if os.path.exists(filename):
                with open(filename, "rb") as f:
                    # Serve PHP content
                    serve_php(client, filename)
                    print("PHP File sent")
            else:
                # If file not found, send a 404 response
                client.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n")

        # If it's a GET request and the file is an HTML file
        elif request_method == "GET" and file_requested.endswith(".html"):
            filename = os.path.join("htdocs", file_requested[1:])
            if os.path.exists(filename):
                with open(filename, "rb") as f:
                    # Send the HTML content
                    client.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n")
                    client.sendall(b"Content-Type: text/html\n\n")
                    client.sendall(f.read())
                    print("HTML File sent")
            else:
                # If file not found, send a 404 response
                client.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n")

        # If it's a POST request and the file is a PHP file (similar to GET)
        elif request_method == "POST" and file_requested.endswith(".php"):
            filename = os.path.join("htdocs", file_requested[1:])
            if os.path.exists(filename):
                with open(filename, "rb") as f:
                    serve_php(client, filename)
                    print("PHP POST File sent")
            else:
                client.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n")

        # If it's a POST request and the file is an HTML file (similar to GET)
        elif request_method == "POST" and file_requested.endswith(".html"):
            filename = os.path.join("htdocs", file_requested[1:])
            if os.path.exists(filename):
                with open(filename, "rb") as f:
                    client.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n")
                    client.sendall(b"Content-Type: text/html\n\n")
                    client.sendall(f.read())
                    print("HTML POST File sent")
            else:
                client.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n")

        # If the request is for the root directory
        elif request_method == "GET" and (file_requested == "/" or file_requested.endswith("/")):
            filename = os.path.join("htdocs", "index.php")
            if os.path.exists(filename):
                with open(filename, "rb") as f:
                    client.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n")
                    client.sendall(b"Content-Type: text/html\n\n")
                    client.sendall(f.read())
                    print("PHP File sent")
            else:
                client.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n")
        else:
            # If the request doesn't match any of the above cases, send a 404 response
            client.sendall(b"HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n")

    # Close the client connection
    client.close()

# Function to run the server
def run_server():
    
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # Create a socket object for IPv4 communication
    
    # Bind the server to the specified port and start listening for incoming connections
    server.bind(('localhost', PORT))
    server.listen(5)

    
    print(f"Server listening on port {2728}")  # Print a message indicating the server is running

    # Accept and handle incoming connections
    while True:
        client, addr = server.accept()
        handle_client(client)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_server()
```

I've also provided a PHP form (form1.php) that collects two numbers and sends them to another PHP script (form2.php) for processing. When I submit the form, the values don't seem to be reaching the server.

Here's the code for form1.php:

```
<html>
<style>
body
{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #c5bde1;
}
div
{
  color: #FF0000;  
}
#form
{
  color: #000;
  border: 0px solid #afafaf;
font-weight: bold;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 35%;
  margin-top: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #777;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 255);
}

input
{
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #afafaf;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  outline: none;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

</style>
<body>
<div id="form">
  <h3>Adding Two Numbers</h3>
  <div class= "text-success" style="text-align: center" id="error">
                    <?php$_REQUEST['msg'] { ?>
                   </div>
  <form action="form2.php">
  <label for="numb1">Number 1:</label>
  <input type="text" name="numb1" id="numb1"  placeholder="First Number"/>
  <br>
  <label for="numb2">Number 2:</label>
  <input type="text" name="numb2" id="numb2"  placeholder="Second Number" />
  <br>
  <button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="reset" name="clear" class="btn btn-primary">Clear</button>
  </form>
  
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $("form").submit(function(){
         var numb1=$("#numb1").val();
         var numb2=$("#numb2").val();
         
         var pat=/^[0-9]+$/;//old nic
         
         
         if(numb1==""){
             $("#error").text("Enter a value");
             $("#numb1").focus();
             return false;
         }
          
          if(!numb1.match(pat)){
             $("#error").text("Enter a number");
             $("#numb1").focus();
             return false;
         }
          
         if(numb2==""){
             $("#error").text("Enter a value");
             $("#numb2").focus();
             return false;
         }
          if(!numb2.match(pat)){
             $("#error").text("Enter a number");
             $("#numb1").focus();
             return false;
         }
          
         });
     });
      </script>
      <script>
     function displayMsg(m){
         var r=confirm("Do You want to "+m);
         if(r){
             return true;
         }else{
             return false;
         }
     }
    </script> 
      
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the code for form2.php:

```
<?php   
        $number1 = $_GET['numb1'];  
        $number2 = $_GET['numb2'];  
        $sum =  $number1+$number2;  
?>  
<html>
<style>


body
{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #c0c0ff;
}

#form
{
  color: #000;
  border: 0px solid #afafaf;
font-weight: bold;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 35%;
  margin-top: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #777;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 255);
}

input
{
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #afafaf;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  outline: none;
}



</style>
<body>
<div id="form">
  <h3>Adding Two Numbers</h3>
  <label for="num1">Number 01:</label>
  <input type="text" name="numb1" value="<?php echo  $_GET['numb1'];?>" disabled="" />
  <br>
  <label for="num1">Number 02:</label>
  <input type="text" name="numb2" value="<?php echo  $_GET['numb2'];?>" disabled=""/>
  <br>
<label for="total">Total value:</label>
<input type="text" name="total" value="<?php echo $sum ?>"disabled=""/>
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've ensured that the form method is set to POST. Am I missing something in my server code that might be causing the issue with handling POST requests?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

*I tried changing the form method to POST and made sure that the form fields were named correctly. I also checked the browser's developer console for any error messages, but I didn't find anything relevant.*

Comment: The CLI version of PHP knows nothing about forms. You need to use the CGI version and follow the CGI specification.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm using the Python server to handle HTTP requests, and it executes PHP scripts. GET requests work, but I'm having trouble with POST requests. Could you guide me on handling POST requests with a Python server and PHP?

Comment: *"GET requests work"* No, they don't. `$_GET` is not populated by CLI PHP. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186392/php-passing-get-in-the-linux-command-prompt) for more details.